# jQuery calls to page method vs web service vs Web API

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, pagemethods

I'm working on an ASP.NET Web Forms application and I see a lot of areas where the page posts back after a dropdownlist selection is made, during which a small amount of data is retrieved from the server to populate another control (like a textbox).

It's not a nice user experience to have the page posting back every time you make a selection, especially if there are 5+ dropdowns on the page. To eliminate these postbacks I'm thinking of implementing jQuery Ajax calls (which I already have experience with).

Which is recommended: page methods or .asmx web services? Aren't .asmx web services considered 'older' technology?

And further, I have been reading up on Web API. Could this be an alternative to a page method or web service? Would Web API be overkill simply to eliminate a bunch of simple postbacks?

Answer (score 0):

The first question I'd ask is... "what's overkill here?". The WebAPI, basically, is the latest implementation of a data retrieval proxy by Microsoft that supports multiple formats (XML/ODATA/JSON etc).

It's simple to setup, future-proof and you can use it as a stand-alone service in its own separate project if you feel the need to; that alone makes me use it in my .NET projects now and I've not looked back.

Answer (score 0):

Well, i'll first answer you that it depends on the situation first. But if you are interested in deeply study, i suggest you an article which greatly explain the difference between `Page Methods` and `Web Mthods`.
In my perspective page methods are considered to be faster and here is why? 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163480.aspx **(see the second last paragraph of the article)**
On the other hand `Web Api` is considered to be lightwight and makes it easy to build HTTP services that reach a broad range of clients.You can use XML or JSON or something else with your API. JSON is nice for mobile apps with slow connections, for example. You can call an API from jQuery and better utilize the client's machine and browser.